# API Webscrape OpenFDA with R

Tags: r, api

I am scraping OpenFDA (https://open.fda.gov/apis).  I know my particular inquiry has 6974 hits, which is organized into 100 hits per page (max download of the API).  I am trying to use R (rvest, jsonlite, purr, tidyverse, httr) to download all of this data.

I checked the website information with curl in terminal and downloaded a couple of sites to see a pattern.

I've tried a few lines of code and I can only get 100 entries to download.  This code seems to work decently, but it will only pull 100 entries, so one page  To skip the fisrt 100, which I can pull down and merge later, here is the code that I have used:

```
url_json <- "https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?api_key=YOULLHAVETOGETAKEY&search=grapefruit&limit=100&skip=6973"

raw_json <- httr::GET(url_json, accept_json())
data<- httr::content(raw_json, "text")
my_content_from_json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(data)
dplyr::glimpse(my_content_from_json)
dataframe1 <- my_content_from_json$results
view(dataframe1)


SOLUTION below in the responses. Thanks!
```

Comment: Where is `new_urls` defined in your code? The documentation seems to recommend using the `Link` meta tag from the response header rather than constructing the link yourself. It's hard to help without a reproducible example

Comment: What data are you trying to extract? It looks like their JSON is a bit of a mess and hard to coerce into a data frame, but you can at least download more entries at once by using limit and skip instead of the searchafter parameter according to their docs: https://open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters/. I was able to request a thousand entries this way but couldn't figure out which bits of information to extract.

Comment: The new urls is the URL that worked with our key on it.  I redacted it but it is similar to the example on the site.

Comment: So, if you do the skip, is it like skip=1&limited=7000 does that extract like entry 1 through 7000?  I tried search after but I had to keep looping the link @Dubukay

Comment: The code above is edited with the input code.

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading through the API docs - they'll save you a lot of time in the end! In that page I shared the `limit` (not limited) parameter has a maximum value of 1000. So the first loop would be &skip=0&limit=1000 then the next would be skip=1000&limit=1000, skip=2000&limit=1000, etc.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is contradictory a bit which is where I was confused.  It says it has a limit at 100 in one spot and 1000 in another spot.  I think this is working now.  Thank you.  I also tried pulling sites sequentially via curl and it just wasn't working efficiently.  This does though!  Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, API documentation is notoriously awful :) glad it's working now! I've turned this comment section into an answer below so others know that it's been solved, feel free to upvote/checkmark if you're happy.

Comment: True story @Dubukay.  But hey, it works now so yay!  :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

It looks like the API parameters `skip` and `limit` work better than the `search_after` parameter. They allow pulling down 1,000 entries simultaneously according to the documentation (open.fda.gov/apis/query-parameters). To provide these parameters into the query string, an example URL would be

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?api_key=YOULLHAVETOGETAKEY&search=grapefruit&limit=1000&skip=0
```

after which you can loop to get the remaining entries with `skip=1000`, skip=`2000`, etc. as you've done above.

Comment: Yep that worked!!  :)  For anyone using that API, it works great!!!